# How to create a functioning progress bar in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple script which only has `apt-get update`. When I run it I want it to show a progress bar instead of showing all that updating it shows when you run it normally.

This code creates a progress bar, but how do I implement it so it shows a progress bar and not all the lines which it normally shows?

```
require 'progress_bar'
bar = ProgressBar.new

100.times do
  sleep 0.1
  bar.increment!
end
```

Comment: You have to be able to get a reasonable estimate of the number of loops it'll take to accomplish something, or the number of blocks of data will be moved, otherwise you can't create a useful progress bar. `apt-get` won't tell you how many things it has to do because it won't know until it runs `update`. You _could_ run it twice so you could grab the information from the first run, but that'd take twice as long. Search the internet for writing progress bars and you'll find out a lot more, such as http://askubuntu.com/q/445245.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment of Tin Man: You need to have access to the process so that you know how many times something is going to occur. I don't know of the apt-get process but it seems like it won't be possible.

I can give you an example of code I use to download files but it is not easy to explain.

What the method needs to do is buried in the `File.open` block, writing the received input to a file, the rest is used to pass information to the progressbar.

Basically you need two things:

1. a length (out of how many steps consist your action)
2. a progress block which detemines when a step (piece of the work) is done and thus a progressmarker is displayed.

Both are implemented as lambdas:

```
require 'ruby-progressbar'

def download url, file, folder
  pbar = nil
  open(url, "rb",
    :content_length_proc => lambda {|t|
     if t && 0 < t
       pbar = ProgressBar.create(title: file, total:t, progress_mark:'█'.encode('utf-8')) 
     end
    },
    :progress_proc => lambda {|s|
     pbar.progress = s if pbar
    }) do |page|
    File.open("#{folder}/#{file}", "wb") do |f|
      while chunk = page.read(1024)
        f.write(chunk)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here an example of what is shown, the title of the bar is the filename being downloaded, followed by the markers.
In total 80 characters are displayed, so the result is neatly aligned at the right in your console. In this setup the number of markers needed is calculated depending on the content_length and the resulting space on the screen.

```
23b31538241754716ea6db15a634e9b2.jpg: |████████████████████████████████████████|
```

Comment: This works when you can get inside a completion loop, and/or know how many times something has to occur, but the OP needs to know for apt-get, which won't let that happen.

Comment: thnx Tin Man, I have no experience with apt-get, so it seems he won't be able to do what he asks, I'll adapt my answer but leave it in place for other uses.